# Exception in thread "main" com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'mail' or call 'Send()' was not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have written a program to send mail using gmail, its working fine if I execute it separately but When I integrating with google appengine its giving me the below error,

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'mail' or call 'Send()' was not found.
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:104)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:56)
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.doSend(MailServiceImpl.java:98)
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.send(MailServiceImpl.java:34)
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport.sendMessage(GMTransport.java:231)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:95)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
at in.javadomain.PostMail.postMailMethod(PostMail.java:49)
at in.javadomain.PostMail.main(PostMail.java:20)
```

I am sure that no integration error or mistakes. I have added javax.mail jar also already.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup the test environment properly, like this:

```java
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
    new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalMailServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}
```

GAE requires these dependencies:

```xml
<properties>
  <gae.version>1.9.17</gae.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
  <version>${gae.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
  <version>${gae.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
  <version>${gae.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, need some further elaboration on how to update the pom.xml with the appengine test dependencies though.